# emails not deliver to outlook account Using yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: php, swift, yii2

While sending email from my website emails delivered to gmail accounts but Emails not deliver to Outlook account, i am using yii2 swift mailer configuration in yii2 config file

```
`mailer' => [
  'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
  'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
  'useFileTransport' => false,
  'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'mail.sample.in',
        'username' => 'develop@sample.in',
        'password' => 'dev98761XXX',
        'port' => '25',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
  ],
],
```

Comment: i dont think that has anything related at Yii end, as it is sending email from its end check the inbox for junk mails or spam for outlook

Comment: I have checked in spam but not found

Comment: you must assign a valid host .. are you sure your  'mail.sample.in', is a valid mail server ??'

Comment: I have given the valid host

Comment: What is the result of method `send()`?

Comment: if i send email to gmail accounts its working fine..but if i change the delivery adders to outlook.. message is not getting. and no error is showing.. i checked in my server, In server it is showing mail sent

Comment: please help me.. I am stucked